# JMeter: Extracting and passing Transaction controller name in JMeter test plan

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In my JMeter test plan, i have 3 transaction controllers.
I want to extract the transaction controller name and pass it to the Jmeter script.
I am unable to extract the transaction controller name, which is displayed into "Log viewer Panel".

To print transaction name , i have used BeanShell Listener, with following code :

```
String tname= sampleResult.toString();

if(tname.startsWith("T01_Login"))
{
log.info("*Transaction Name = " +sampleResult.toString() + " - Response time = " + sampleResult.getTime());
String temp = sampleResult.toString();
String temp2 = sampleResult.getTime().toString();
vars.put("Transaction_Name",temp);
vars.put("Response", temp2);
log.info(vars.get("Response"));
log.info(vars.get("Transaction_Name"));
}
```

I have used BSF post processor to store/extract the transaction name, by using following code:

Language selected in : Javascript

```
var transact = ${Transaction_Name};
vars.put ("TRANSACT",transact);
log.info(TRANSACT);
```

When checked into LogViewer panel, following text is displayed:

```
2017/03/27 17:06:13 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: *Transaction Name = T01_Login - Response time = 39829 
2017/03/27 17:06:13 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: 39829 
2017/03/27 17:06:13 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: T01_Login
```

Kindly provide your valuable suggestion on this.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the error which prevents post-processor from running, use `vars.get`, instead of `var transact = ${Transaction_Name};`, i.e.

```
var transact = vars.get("Transaction_Name");
```

And setting another variable (`vars.put ("TRANSACT",transact);`) is unnecessary: just use `Transaction_Name`. (And another small note: BSF set of objects is now deprecated, so switch them to either JSR322 or BeanShell)

But it will not work anyways, because the order of execution is

```
Sampler > Post-processor > Listener > Transaction Controller > Listener
```

So the value of `Transaction_Name` inside post-processor will either be empty (on first iteration), or will be coming from previous iteration, which I guess is not what you want.

You don't mention your use case, but some options you have are:

1. Have a special sampler AFTER transaction controller to do what you wanted in that post-processor. For example:

   ```
   Transaction Controller
       Some Sampler 
       ...
   JSR223 / Beanshell sampler
   ```

   This second sampler can obtain proper transaction name, since it's running after the transaction
2. Save transaction name into variable before calling a transaction. Set transaction controller name to that variable:

   ```
   JSR223 / Beanshell sampler 
     sets variable: vars.put("Transaction_Name", "T01_Login"); 
   ${Transaction_Name} <-- this is the name of the transaction controller
       Sampler
           Post-processor <-- here the Transaction_Name can be obtained.
   ```

Comment: Thanks Kiril S,for your valuable suggestion , my use case is, i have to extract the transaction controller name along with its response time(as per the test plan execution) and push it into Database of my local machine, could you please provide suggestion for the same .